# Why are some targets run twice when I "mvn package"?

Tags: maven

The full pom.xml file can be viewed [here](https://raw.github.com/fge/uri-template/master/pom.xml). There is one thing I do not understand, as the subject says: when I run `mvn package`, some phases are run twice, as the output of the command shows:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building uri-template 0.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- serviceloader-maven-plugin:1.0.2:generate (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Scanning generated classes for implementations...
[INFO] Generating service file /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes/META-INF/services/com.github.fge.msgsimple.serviceloader.MessageBundleProvider
[INFO]   + com.github.fge.uritemplate.URITemplateMessageBundle
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@31c480e8
Tests run: 513, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.384 sec

Results :

Tests run: 513, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:bundle (default-bundle) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[snip]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
     [echo] /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes/META-INF/services/com.github.fge.msgsimple.serviceloader.MessageBundleProvider
      [jar] Updating jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-repository-plugin:2.3.1:bundle-create (default) @ uri-template >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- serviceloader-maven-plugin:1.0.2:generate (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Scanning generated classes for implementations...
[INFO] Generating service file /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes/META-INF/services/com.github.fge.msgsimple.serviceloader.MessageBundleProvider
[INFO]   + com.github.fge.uritemplate.URITemplateMessageBundle
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:bundle (default-bundle) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9:jar (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[snip]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[WARNING] Artifact com.github.fge:uri-template:javadoc:javadoc:0.5-SNAPSHOT already attached to project, ignoring duplicate
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (default) @ uri-template ---
[WARNING] Artifact com.github.fge:uri-template:java-source:sources:0.5-SNAPSHOT already attached to project, ignoring duplicate
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
     [echo] /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/classes/META-INF/services/com.github.fge.msgsimple.serviceloader.MessageBundleProvider
      [jar] Updating jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-repository-plugin:2.3.1:bundle-create (default) @ uri-template <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-repository-plugin:2.3.1:bundle-create (default) @ uri-template ---
[INFO] The following files are marked for inclusion in the repository bundle:

0.) Done
1.) uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
2.) uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
3.) uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar

Please select the number(s) for any files you wish to exclude, or '0' when you're done.
Separate the numbers for multiple files with a comma (',').

Selection: 
[INFO] Building jar: /home/fge/src/perso/uri-template/target/uri-template-0.5-SNAPSHOT-bundle.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.700s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 11 11:54:38 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/338M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why does this happen? How can I avoid this?

Side question: how can I prevent the repository plugin from being interactive?

Comment: What do you mean in particular? The first one is `default-compile` which compiles the production code whereas the `default-testCompile` will compile the unit test code. Apart from the above in Maven you have a life cycle which will run the plugins which are bound to the appropriate life cycle phase. There does not exist a thing like 'targets'. If you are talking about the things which happen after the [javadoc plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) which forks the life-cycle as stated in the docs.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. The `default-compile` is called twice, for instance. Why? I have googled a lot to try and find a good explanation for this and could not come up with _anything_.

Comment: The problem is caused by two things. First the maven-repository-plugin is usually called from command line and not within the pom file, cause the [maven-repository-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-repository-plugin/usage.html) forkes the life-cycle. which is causing serveral exeuctions of the default-compiler etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first change the configuration for maven-source-plugin like the following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

second you should comment out the execution of the maven-repository-plugin cause the plugin forkes the life-cycle:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-repository-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle-create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After changing the two things above you won't get duplicated executions of default-compile etc.

Comment: This and the comment mentioning that you should run the repository from the command line only indeed removed duplicates! Thanks! Now I have sooo many other questions... But these will be for later!